# How do I align the 3d cursor to a rotated edge?

Tags: mesh, transforms, 3d-cursor

I've been working on creating a race track for a game, and I am currently trying to give the corners camber. The road itself was made with a plane following a path that carved out the shape, and was converted to a mesh.

Currently, I am trying to rotate the track a couple degrees in specific areas and make smooth banking, however rotating it on one axis does not give me consistent rotation for each edge. My solution for this was moving the 3d cursor to the center of the edge and rotating it around that, however lining it up manually is rather tedious, so I was hoping there might be a way to do it automatically.

**In short, I was wondering if there's some way to align the 3d cursor's rotation to a row of vertices.**

Transform orientation is set to cursor, and the pivot point is set to the 3d cursor.

My current process is as follows:

1. Select the center of the road and align the cursor to it. (Select vertex, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, cursor to selected)

   [image: cursor placed on vertex]
2. Carefully rotate the cursor to the correct rotation (Using the N panel and shifting the rotation)

   [image]
3. Rotate the edge to the proper angle. (<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>6</kbd> in this case)

   [image]

As you might be able to tell, this process is rather tedious, because I have to zoom in and find the proper angle instead of just being able to put the cursor down and have it be rotated already, or just not have to put it down in the first place.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I can provide more pictures and information if necessary.